# Find the joint distribution of $(\frac{X}{X+Y},X+Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, jacobian

This problem is about joint probability distributions.

Let $X,Y$ be i.i.d. random variables, each exponential $E(1)$.
I wish to find the distribution of $(A,B)$
where $A = \frac{X}{X+Y}$, $B = X+Y$. Equivalently, $X=AB, \, Y=B(1-A)$.

From the Jacobian method,

$$J(A,B)=\begin{vmatrix}
B & A \\
-B & 1-A \\
\end{vmatrix}=B$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Use the jacobian method. If you write your efforts I will help you where you are stuck.

Comment: You've made a start in your edit, so I'll explain the strategy. Let $f_{X,\,Y}(x,\,y),\,f_{A,\,B}(a,\,b)$ denote the respective joint PDFs so$$f_{A,\,B}(a,\,b)dadb=f_{X,\,Y}(x,\,y)dxdy=f_{X,\,Y}(x,\,y)|J|dadb\implies f_{A,\,B}(a,\,b)=f_{X,\,Y}(x,\,y)|J|.$$Just make sure to write the final expression as a function of $a,\,b$ rather than $x,\,y$. You should find $A,\,B$ are independent with $A\sim U(0,\,1),\,B\sim\Gamma(2,\,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

To check that $A\perp\!\!\!\perp B$ you can use another method...

Observe that

- $B=X+Y$ is Complete and Sufficient Statistic
- $A=\frac{X}{X+Y}$ is scale invariant statistic

Being the model also scale invariant, $A$ is ancillary.

Thus, applying Basu's Theorem, you have the proof

To apply Jacobian method is very easy because you immediately find

$$f_{AB}(a,b)=b e^{-b}=1\times b e^{-b}=f_A(a)\times f_B(b)$$

$0\le a\le 1$

$b\ge 0$

Comment: So, don't we need J(A,B)?

Comment: @drango: yes we need it! It's $b$ in $b e^{-b}$

Comment: So the answer is,
_()(,)=f_A(A*B)f_B(B-A*B)*B

ok?